# Rotate UIImageView clockwise

Tags: objective-c, ios, core-graphics, transform, cgaffinetransform

This should be simple, but I'm having trouble rotating a `UIImageView` a full 360 degrees, repeated forever.

```
[UIView animateWithDuration:0.5 delay:0 options:UIViewAnimationOptionAllowUserInteraction | UIViewAnimationOptionRepeat | UIViewAnimationOptionCurveLinear | UIViewAnimationOptionBeginFromCurrentState animations:^{
    self.reloadButton.imageView.transform = CGAffineTransformRotate(self.reloadButton.imageView.transform, -M_PI);
} completion:^(BOOL finished) {

}];
```

According to the docs, the signedness of the angle I pass to `CGAffineTransformRotate` determines the direction of the rotation, but the above code rotates counterclockwise. Same with `M_PI`.

> The angle, in radians, by which this matrix rotates the coordinate
>   system axes. In iOS, a positive value specifies counterclockwise
>   rotation and a negative value specifies clockwise rotation. In Mac OS
>   X, a positive value specifies clockwise rotation and a negative value
>   specifies counterclockwise rotation.

Comment: What happens if you do the rotation on the imageViews layer with a CATransform3D?

Comment: did you try rotating by other angles (say 180 degrees) ?

Comment: @David Thanks for the suggestion but this produced the same results: self.reloadButton.imageView.layer.transform = CATransform3DMakeRotation(-M_PI, 0, 0, 1);

Comment: Since M_PI is 180 degrees it should be the same. what happens if you rotate my M_PI/4  or -M_PI/4? You should see some difference?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Christoph is already going the correct way, but there is a far better way to keep it spinning without reinvoke it in the animation delegates every time it ends. This is simply wrong.

Just set the repeatCount property of your animation to `HUGE_VALF`.

```
CABasicAnimation* animation = [CABasicAnimation animationWithKeyPath:@"transform.rotation.z"];
animation.fromValue = @0.0f;
animation.toValue = @(2*M_PI);
animation.duration = 0.5f;             // this might be too fast
animation.repeatCount = HUGE_VALF;     // HUGE_VALF is defined in math.h so import it
[self.reloadButton.imageView.layer addAnimation:animation forKey:@"rotation"];
```

As stated [in the documentation](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/GraphicsImaging/Reference/CAMediaTiming_protocol/Introduction/Introduction.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40004511-CH1-SW5), this will cause the animation to repeat forever.

Comment: Ok, did not really think about it, because 270 degrees were enough for me. Setting the repeat count is way better, I will change accordingly.

Comment: Just use `CGFLOAT_MAX` instead of importing something.

Comment: Or you directly write `1e50f` since it's all the same... Or we do it as the documentation states.

Comment: @BenLachman actually the docs tell you specifically to use HUGE_VALF. https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/GraphicsImaging/Reference/CAMediaTiming_protocol/index.html#//apple_ref/occ/intfp/CAMediaTiming/repeatCount

Comment: @MikeyWard Good point, I didn't notice that in the docs. Any thoughts on why they specify that? It's the only time `HUGE_VALF` is referenced in all of Apple's docs (outside of strto* man pages). Seems a little odd. Maybe a legacy reference?

Comment: @yinkou Thanks for the snark, alway appreciated. :-) `HUGE_VALF` seems like it might be legacy. See this question about using it in Swift: http://stackoverflow.com/q/24343908/159801 

I think I'll file a documentation bug about it.

Answer (score 1):

Sorry missed first part, view rotates just fine using smaller angle:

```
[UIView animateWithDuration:0.5 delay:0 options:UIViewAnimationOptionAllowUserInteraction | UIViewAnimationOptionRepeat | UIViewAnimationOptionCurveLinear | UIViewAnimationOptionBeginFromCurrentState animations:^{
        redView.transform = CGAffineTransformRotate(redView.transform, M_PI_2);
    } completion:^(BOOL finished) {

    }];
```

I couldn't find any meaningful explanations why it fails with M_PI.

Comment: Repeating is exactly what I want, the problem is that it's not rotating clockwise.

Comment: I think its because the final state of the rotation is the same as the original state

Answer (score 1):

I encountered the same issue a while ago.
I do not remember the reason for that issue, but this is my solution:

```
/**
 * Incrementally rotated the arrow view by a given angle.
 *
 * @param degrees Angle in degrees.
 * @param duration Duration of the rotation animation.
 */
- (void)rotateArrowViewByAngle:(CGFloat)degrees
                  withDuration:(NSTimeInterval)duration {

    CABasicAnimation *spinAnimation = [CABasicAnimation animationWithKeyPath:@"transform.rotation.z"];
    spinAnimation.fromValue = [NSNumber numberWithFloat:self.currentAngle / 180.0 * M_PI];
    spinAnimation.toValue = [NSNumber numberWithFloat:degrees / 180.0 * M_PI];
    spinAnimation.duration = duration;
    spinAnimation.cumulative = YES;
    spinAnimation.additive = YES;
    spinAnimation.removedOnCompletion = NO;
    spinAnimation.delegate = self;
    spinAnimation.fillMode = kCAFillModeForwards;

    [self.arrowView.layer addAnimation:spinAnimation forKey:@"spinAnimation"];

    self.currentAngle = degrees;
}
```

and then you can use the delegate methods

```
- (void)animationDidStart:(CAAnimation *)theAnimation
- (void)animationDidStop:(CAAnimation *)theAnimation finished:(BOOL)flag
```

to rotate keep it rotating.
Also, degree and duration parameters can be really high numbers... if this is enough.

UPDATE:
As stated by yinkou,

```
spinAnimation.repeatCount = HUGE_VALF;     // HUGE_VALF is defined in math.h so import it
```

is way better that restarting the animation in the delegate.

PLEASE NOTE:
self.currentAngle is a property remembering the current final rotation. 
I needed that to make the view rotate left and right way around.

Answer (score 1):

I wrote UIImageView category for this: https://gist.github.com/alexhajdu/5658543.

Just use:

```
[_myImageView rotate360WithDuration:1.0 repeatCount:0]; //0 for infinite loop
```