# how to repeat animation forever in Swift (HUGE_VALF)?

Tags: swift, cabasicanimation

According to the docs, the way to repeat a CABasicAnimation forever is to set its `repeatCount` to `HUGE_VALF`.

But in Swift, `HUGE_VALF` causes a compile error. Swift doesn't seem to know about the standard library (or wherever this constant resides).

What do I do now?

Answer (score 90, accepted):

Set the `repeatCount` to `Float.infinity`. This compiles and works.

In all probability, `HUGE_VALF` was a legacy value in any case.

Still, it's a bit of a surprise that these numeric constant names are not seen by Swift. I did try importing `<stdlib.h>` in the bridging header but it didn't help.

---

But please see now Martin R's answer. Since the time when I posted my answer, Apple has stated their preferred answer explicitly: use `.greatestFiniteMagnitude`. It is almost the same thing as `.infinity` but not quite!

Comment: Good find. I believe you meant `repeatCount` in both Q&A though?

Comment: I didn't mean that, in the sense that my code was in fact setting `repeatDuration` to `HUGE_VALF`. But I probably _should_ have meant that! I'll adjust.

Comment: `HUGE_VALF` is defined in `<math.h>`. But even it that file is added to the bridging header file, *this* constant is not exposed to Swift.

Comment: @MartinR And why is that? That's what I don't understand. It's just lucky I found another approach...

Answer (score 7):

The current documentation for the [`repeatCount`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/quartzcore/camediatiming/1427666-repeatcount) property of [`CAMediaTiming`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/quartzcore/camediatiming) states:

> Setting this property to [`greatestFiniteMagnitude`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/swift/float/1846834-greatestfinitemagnitude) will cause the animation to repeat forever.

And that compiles without problems:

```
let ba = CABasicAnimation()
ba.repeatCount = .greatestFiniteMagnitude
```

The reason that `HUGE_VALF` is not imported into Swift is that
it is defined as a "non-trivial" macro in `<math.h>`:

```
#   define    HUGE_VALF    __builtin_huge_valf()
```

Answer (score 0):

I use the "HUGE" value. it is a build_in readonly var;