# ios UIImageView rotation direction in swift at variable degree in clockwise direction

Tags: ios, animation, rotation, direction

I am rotating image through this code

```
UIView.animate(withDuration: 2) {

        self.blueNeedleImageView.transform = CGAffineTransform(rotationAngle: CGFloat(myDegreeValue * Double.pi / 180))

    }
```

Problem is that it is rotating in shortest path. I want always clockwise rotation and rotation degree is variable. [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18731737/about-cgaffinetransformmakerotation-rotation-direction) and [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10493983/rotate-uiimageview-clockwise) does not provide a solution.

Comment: **Please Note**: The angle is in Radians.

Comment: iPeter I am converting angle to radians by multiplying with  (Double.pi / 180)

Comment: What do you mean by shortest path?

Comment: shortest path mean if want to rotate through 20 degree then it will rotate in clockwise direction but if i want to rotate 340 degree then it will rotate in anti-clockwise direction.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just split it to two animations if the angle is more than 180°.

Comment: nice workaround. but isn't there a proper way because this solution is complicating things.

Comment: It seems like the easiest solution. Note that you can return your view back with `.transform = CGAffineTransformIdentity`

Answer (score 1):

You can rotate your Image as per your requirement with the help of `CoreAnimation` like below:

```
let angle = myDegreeValue
if let n = NumberFormatter().number(from: angle) {
    let floatAngle = Double(truncating: n)
    CATransaction.begin()
    let rotationAnimation = CABasicAnimation(keyPath: "transform.rotation.z")
    rotationAnimation.byValue = NSNumber(value: floatAngle * (Double.pi / 180))
    rotationAnimation.duration = 2
    rotationAnimation.isRemovedOnCompletion = true

    CATransaction.setCompletionBlock {
          self.blueNeedleImageView.transform = CGAffineTransform(rotationAngle: CGFloat(floatAngle * (Double.pi / 180)))
    }
    self.blueNeedleImageView.layer.add(rotationAnimation, forKey: "rotationAnimation")
    CATransaction.commit()
}
```